# Is it possible to iterate through enum members in a constexpr function, so the values are constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose that I want to create a general system which can store variable-width integers together. In this system, we can use an `enum`, which contain member names (this enum members have consecutive values `[0;count)`):

```
enum class Group1 {
    AttrA,
    AttrB,
    AttrC,
};
```

I add `inline constexpr` specialization, which tells, how many members are there:

```
template <typename TYPE>
inline constexpr int count = -1;

template <>
inline constexpr int count<Group1> = 3; // Group1 has 3 members (AttrA/B/C)
```

And I add `inline constexpr` specializations which describes each members width:

```
template <auto VALUE>
inline constexpr int nBits = -1;

template <>
inline constexpr int nBits<Group1::AttrA> = 3; // AttrA need 3 bits of storage
template <>
inline constexpr int nBits<Group1::AttrB> = 2;
template <>
inline constexpr int nBits<Group1::AttrC> = 4;
```

Now, I'd like to have a general `constexpr` function , which can calculate summed width (of any type, not just `Group1`):

```
template <typename TYPE>
constexpr int summedWidth() {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<count<TYPE>; i++) {
        r += nBits<static_cast<TYPE>(i)>;
    }
    return r;
}
```

However, this doesn't compile, because of the `r += nBits...` line:

> error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Is it possible to create a compilable `summedWidth()` function (or any other solution, which provides a compile-time constant)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::make_integer_sequence` to expand `count<TYPE>` into a pack that you can fold over:

```
template <typename TYPE, int... ints>
constexpr int summedWidthHelper(std::integer_sequence<int, ints...>) {
    return (0 + ... + nBits<static_cast<TYPE>(ints)>);
}

template <typename TYPE>
constexpr int summedWidth() {
    return summedWidthHelper<TYPE>(std::make_integer_sequence<int, count<TYPE>>{});
}
```

Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28df4b17d071f6e5

Comment: Why not just use `std::index_sequence`?